# How do I fix interning issues with this macro?

Tags: macros, package, common-lisp, symbols

I've a macro defined in package "a" that defines a function "fun". I'd like to use this macro in package "b" expecting to get "fun" defined in "b" but it ends up getting defined in "a". Can someone please help?

Here's the sample code:

```lisp
(defpackage #:a (:use #:cl) (:export makefun))
(in-package #:a)
(defmacro makefun (&optional (name (package-name *package*)))
  `(defun fun ()
     ,(format nil "hello ~a" name)))

(defpackage #:b (:use #:cl #:a))
(in-package #:b)
(macroexpand-1 '(makefun)) ; expands to (DEFUN A::FUN () "hello B")
(makefun)
(fun) ; fails

(defpackage #:c (:use #:cl #:a))
(in-package #:c)
(macroexpand-1 '(makefun)) ; expands to (DEFUN A::FUN () "hello C")
(makefun)
(fun) ; fails
```

Comment: Do (import 'a::fun) after (makefun). That should import the newly created function into package :b, and then you can call (fun) from :b.

Comment: @Leo Thank you. Might work in this simple case but not in mine I'm afraid. The actual code (makefun) uses the package name to access database specific schema and this was supposed to be invoked from multiple packages. Multiple invocations would end up overwriting each other in package "a". I'll edit the code to reflect this.

Comment: @Leo Sorry I meant to ask, won't multiple invocations end up overwriting each other in package "a"?

Comment: If you want FUN to be in package B, then you have to generate the symbol B::FUN.

Comment: @rainer Thank you, does that mean importing them specifically as Leo mentioned is the only solution? And why isn't the :use in the package definition not helping here? Is there another way I write this piece of code without having to worry about importing individual functions across many packages? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @rebnoob I suspect that `fun` is not exported from package A, so even if you use the package, it will not be visible to the casual onlooker in a different package.

Answer (score 1):

If what you really want to do is have it making the function name in the dynamically-current package you want to do something like this:

```
(defmacro makefun (&optional (name (package-name *package*)))
  (let ((funn (intern (symbol-name 'fun) *package*)))
    `(defun ,funn ()
       ,(format nil "hello ~a" name))))
```

However this smells like an XY problem to me: I don't know what the problem you're trying to solve is but there is very likely to be a better solution than lots of different functions all with the same name but in different packages.